# Who calls onStartup(ServletContext) method on Spring DynamicRegistrationBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

DynamicRegistrationBean is used to register servlets and filters in the ApplicationContext and this registration happens in onStartup(..) method.

Per ServletContextInitializer(which DynamicRegistrationBean implememts) Java Docs...

> This interface is primarily designed to allow 
>   "ServletContextInitializers" to be managed by Spring and not the
>   Servlet container.

My question is, when does spring call onStartup(..) method on DynamicRegistrationBean bean.